# How to set the regex to extract strings in python

Tags: python, regex

The strings have two types.
The first type:

```
'The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:'
#Doesn't contain "("
```

The second type:

```
'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]'
#Containing "("
```

If the string contains "(", remove all characters after"(" and the white space before"(".
If not, extract all characters.

I have firgured out how to extract second type of strings .

```
r'(.+) \('
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this.

```
university = 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]'
print(university.split("(", 1)[0].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` to remove everything after `(` if you want to use regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r' \(.*', '', 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]')
# 'Tuskegee'

re.sub(r' \(.*', '', 'The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:')
# 'The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex `re.sub('\s*\(.*',..)` to match whitespace plus a "(". 
If this matches, it will replace this with the empty string. If not, nothing is replaced.

```
import re
re.sub('\s*\(.*', '', 'The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:')
#'The Five College Region of Western Massachusetts:'
re.sub('\s*\(.*', '', 'Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]')
#'Tuskegee'
```